# why can't we access 2D array as of 1D array? How can i access?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why can't we access a 2D array as of 1D array? How can I access?

Array function:

```
int **combination(int no)
{

int i,j,c=0;
static int arr[100][2];

for(i=0;i<=no;i++){
    for(j=0;j<=no;j++){
        if(((i+j)==no)){
            arr[c][0]=i;
            arr[c][1]=j;
            c++;
            }
    }
}

return arr;
}
```

Main function:

```
int main() {
    int n,k,i;
    int **arr;
    int size=10;//let us assume.

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    fprintf(stderr, "1\n");
    arr=combination(n);
    fprintf(stderr, "2\n");

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    printf("%d-%d",arr[i][0],arr[i][1]);
}
    return 0;
}
```

It is showing:

> `.c:29:8: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`
>   `return arr`

and segmentation fault core dumped.

Can you suggest what is the pointer type to call to access the element from that 2D array?

Comment: Your `combination` function can be simplified. Since you are only considering the case when `(i+j) == no`, you can directly determine `j` when this is true with the expression `j = no - i`. You then need only one loop and the execution will be faster. The value `c` is then equal to `i`. Note that you should verify the function argument so that `no < 100`, and report an error otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for better approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `int arr[100][2]` (*a pointer to array of int [2]*) is not compatible with  `int**` (*a pointer to pointer to int*).

Why?

[C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

> *Array pointer conversion*
>
> (p3) Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the
>   `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `'&'` operator, or is a *string
>   literal* used to initialize an array, an expression that has type
>   *"array of type"* is converted to an expression with type *"pointer to type"* that points to the initial element of the array object and is
>   not an lvalue.

Applying 6.3.2.1(p3) to `int arr[100][2]`, the result is `int (*arr)[2]` (*a pointer to array of int [2]*) which is not `int**`. So your compiler properly generates the warning.

If you really want to do it this way, then in `main()` change your declaration of `arr` to:

```
    int (*arr)[2];
```

And then change your function declaration to:

```
int (*(combination)(int no))[2]
```

(a *function* taking `(int no)` returning `int (*...)[2]` *a pointer to array of `int` [2]*)

You should also limit the value of `c` in your function to less than `100` to prevent exceeding your array bounds.